# Can dispatchEvent() carry arguments in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, parameters, addeventlistener, dispatchevent

Behold this example:

```
addEventListener("myEventType", myFunction("argument"));

function myFunction(args:String):Function {
    return function(evt:Event):void {
        trace(evt.currentTarget, "has", args);
    };
}

dispatchEvent(new Event("myEventType", true));
```

It works.

Can I do something similar, but passing `"argument"` through `dispatchEvent()`?

It'd be very handy in a situation where `dispatchEvent()` is in a wholly separated class from `addEventListener()` and `myFunction()`.

I'll be needing this a lot, so I want to do it without creating a custom event class for every situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use native `flash.events.DataEvent` for passing `String` parameter or create custom `DataEvent` with `data:*` property in all situations where you need to pass parameters to event handler.

If you want to customize the behavior of event listener in the place of adding event listener you can create "listener" object for holding this custom parameters (but I think this technique is more complicated than custom events):
`addEventListener("myEventType", new EventListener("param1").onEvent);`, where`EventListener` is the class like this:

```
public class EventListener
{
    private var params:*;

    public function EventListener(params:*)
    {
            this.params = params;
    }

    public function onEvent(event:Event):void
    {
            trace("onEvent, params = ", params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Signals (https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals). They are an alternative to Events and you can send whatever extra params you want with a Signal.